# Proving this sequence is unbounded

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-writing

> I need to prove that the following sequence is unbounded:
>
> $$ Z_n := \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^2} $$ for $n\in \mathbb N$.

I know that I essentially need to show that $\forall M \in\mathbb{R}$ there exists $z_N \in Z$ such that $M < z_N$, i.e.,
$$ M < \left(1+\frac{1}{N}\right)^{N^2}, N\in\mathbb{N}$$
But frankly, I'm lost as to how to prove that.

I was able to prove that $(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n}$ was bounded above by say, 3, by using the fact that $$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n} = \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{n^k} = \sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k!}(1)\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1-\frac{2}{n}\right)\dots\left(1-\frac{k-1}{n}\right)$$
and then showing that
$$\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k!}(1)\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1-\frac{2}{n}\right)\dots\left(1-\frac{k-1}{n}\right) < \sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{2^k} < 3 \text{ (telescoping sum)}$$
But the same method does not work for the sequence $Z_n$. Any ideas?
(Please have mercy)

Thanks!

Comment: $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ approaches e as n approaches infinity, so your sequence should approach $e^n$, which is unbounded. I'm not sure how to make this rigorous, but hopefully it is helpful

Comment: More specifically, $(1 + \frac{1}{n})^n$ INCREASES to $e,$ in particular it is larger than $2$ for $n > 1$

Comment: $(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n^2}$ = ($1 + n^2*\frac{1}{n}$ + ... +$\frac{1}{n^{n^2}}$) > (1 + n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We prove that $(1+1/n)^n \geqslant 2 [n \in \mathbb N^*]$, and $Z_n$ is therefore unbounded.

By the binomial theorem, 
$$
\left(1 + \frac 1n\right)^n = \sum_0^n \binom n k \frac 1{n^k} \geqslant \sum_0^1 \binom n k \frac 1{n^k} = \binom n 0 + \binom n1 \cdot \frac 1 n = 1 + 1 =2, 
$$
hence
$$
Z_n \geqslant 2^n,
$$
and $(2^n)_1^\infty$ is unbounded.

Comment: Oh of course! Thank you this was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Bernoulli inequality says that $$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^2}\geq 1+\frac{n^2}{n}=n+1$$ and we are done.